# platform io and partition tables

Tags: visual-studio-code, io, esp32, platform, esp-idf

I am working on a project with VSCode and Platform IO that needs a new partition table. I have copied the partition csv file in the root of the project. When i compile the project i get this error message

[image]

This is the partition table that i use

[image]

This is my platformIO.ini file

[image]

I am not familiar with partition table so i do not know what is wrong here. Can someone help me
Thanks in advance

tonnie

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the [esp32doit-devkit-v1](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/espressif32/esp32doit-devkit-v1.html) has 4MB of flash memory. Not all of it can be used for your application(s) because *bootloader, nvs, phy_config, etc.* need some of it.
Quoting the from the [partition tables documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html) the default partition size for an application (e.g. `factory` or `ota_1` or `ota_2`) is `1M`. Seen here in the example for “*Factory app, two OTA definitions*”

```
# ESP-IDF Partition Table
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x4000,
otadata,  data, ota,     0xd000,  0x2000,
phy_init, data, phy,     0xf000,  0x1000,
factory,  app,  factory, 0x10000,  1M,
ota_0,    app,  ota_0,   0x110000, 1M,
ota_1,    app,  ota_1,   0x210000, 1M,
```

Meaning the `1M` --> 10124 * 1024 --> 1048576 (Bytes) (refer to your screenshot).
The firmware you are building consumes `1060221`Bytes which is greater than this (default) partition size...

This is probably due to the fact that in your partition table the size for `ota_1` and `ota_2` is set to `1984K` (1984 * 1024 --> 2031616Bytes) and in combination with the other necessary partitions and the offset due to the booatloader is exceeding the 4MB flash (roughly estimated).
I assume a check during the creation of the partition table prevents overuse and sets the partition size back to the default size.

Try to use the following partition table and increase the partition size for `ota_1` and `ota_2` if necessary

```
# ESP-IDF Partition Table
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,           ,  0x4000,
otadata,  data, ota,           ,  0x2000,
phy_init, data, phy,           ,  0x1000,
ota_0,    app,  ota_0,         ,  1200K,
ota_1,    app,  ota_1,         ,  1200K,
```